# Edgeline EL8000 not able to process provider network traffic with OpenStack

Tags: linux-networking, hp, openstack, hpe

I am currently trying to install OpenStack on an Edgeline EL8000 that has 4 server blades. I have OpenStack running and configured but I am unable to create a provider flat network on my home network for computers to reach out. I can hit the networks dhcp provider and other computers in Nova, but I cannot hit the actual gateway.

The OpenStack configuration is multinode with all servers (openstack1-4) having same login, os (ubuntu), and interfaces.

Globals.yml

```
workaround_ansible_issue_8743: yes
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "192.168.100.10"
network_interface: "eno1"
neutron_external_interface: "eno2np0"

enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "yes"
enable_neutron_provider_networks: "yes"
```

interfaces (compute)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ba:2c:25:ec:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 192.168.100.6/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ed:8c:5e:85:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp193s0f0np0
    inet6 fe80::5eed:8cff:fe5e:854c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ed:8c:5e:85:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp193s0f1np1
    inet6 fe80::5eed:8cff:fe5e:854d/64 scope link
```

interfaces (all others):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ba:2c:25:eb:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 192.168.100.7/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.100.10/32 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2603:3023:a43:21c0:5eba:2cff:fe25:eb9d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 256901sec preferred_lft 256901sec
    inet6 fe80::5eba:2cff:fe25:eb9d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ed:8c:5e:84:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp193s0f0np0
    inet6 fe80::5eed:8cff:fe5e:840e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:ed:8c:5e:84:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp193s0f1np1
    inet6 fe80::5eed:8cff:fe5e:840f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
The network runs off of 192.168.0.0/16 with the gateway being 192.168.200.100
```

ovs-vsctl of compute node:

```
666073c9-5873-457d-aac5-34c99d963f11
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port tap92902be9-c3
            tag: 2
            Interface tap92902be9-c3
                type: internal
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
    Bridge br-tun
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
    Bridge br-ex
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
                error: "could not add network device br-ex to ofproto (File exists)"
        Port eno2np0
            Interface eno2np0
```

ovs-vsctl of all other nodes:

```
c9849b82-ce07-4478-8e13-d2baf483607b
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-ex
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port eno2np0
            Interface eno2np0
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
    Bridge br-tun
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
```

The network is created as phsynet1

Created network:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                   |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        |                                      |
| created_at                | 2023-06-08T23:22:26Z                 |
| description               |                                      |
| dns_domain                | None                                 |
| id                        | dbe40133-81af-4719-8d3d-53106d5d6121 |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                 |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                 |
| is_default                | False                                |
| is_vlan_transparent       | None                                 |
| mtu                       | 1500                                 |
| name                      | phsynet1                             |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                 |
| project_id                | a3671e540d01420a8114e47aaa7e0721     |
| provider:network_type     | flat                                 |
| provider:physical_network | physnet1                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | None                                 |
| qos_policy_id             | None                                 |
| revision_number           | 1                                    |
| router:external           | External                             |
| segments                  | None                                 |
| shared                    | True                                 |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   |                                      |
| tags                      |                                      |
| updated_at                | 2023-06-08T23:22:27Z                 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Created subnet

```
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                | Value                                |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| allocation_pools     | 192.168.100.50-192.168.100.100       |
| cidr                 | 192.168.0.0/16                       |
| created_at           | 2023-06-08T23:24:34Z                 |
| description          |                                      |
| dns_nameservers      | 192.168.200.100                      |
| dns_publish_fixed_ip | None                                 |
| enable_dhcp          | True                                 |
| gateway_ip           | 192.168.200.100                      |
| host_routes          |                                      |
| id                   | 45d1c434-6b5d-4f1b-bd80-6127e190b4b2 |
| ip_version           | 4                                    |
| ipv6_address_mode    | None                                 |
| ipv6_ra_mode         | None                                 |
| name                 | physnet1                             |
| network_id           | dbe40133-81af-4719-8d3d-53106d5d6121 |
| project_id           | a3671e540d01420a8114e47aaa7e0721     |
| revision_number      | 0                                    |
| segment_id           | None                                 |
| service_types        |                                      |
| subnetpool_id        | None                                 |
| tags                 |                                      |
| updated_at           | 2023-06-08T23:24:34Z                 |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Trying to figure out what I did wrong that caused Neutron to have issues with connecting to the physical network.